# How to retrieve Subscriber Profile Attributes from an Enterprise 2.0 account?

Tags: api, marketing-cloud, ampscript

How to retrieve a profile attribute value of a subscriber from an Enterprise 2.0 account?

I have the following, but this is only for Subscriber Properties.

Thanks

```
SET @retrieveRequest = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@retrieveRequest,"ObjectType","Subscriber")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest,"Properties","SubscriberKey")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest,"Properties","EmailAddress")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest,"Properties","Status")

SET @simpleFilterPart = CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart")
SetObjectProperty(@simpleFilterPart,"Property","SubscriberKey")
SetObjectProperty(@simpleFilterPart,"SimpleOperator","equals")
AddObjectArrayItem(@simpleFilterPart,"Value","orangeexperts@outlook.com")

SetObjectProperty(@retrieveRequest,"Filter",@simpleFilterPart)

/* Check Subscriber Exists */
SET @retrieveRequestRS = InvokeRetrieve(@retrieveRequest, @status)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add: AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest,"Properties","ID")

This will make it so it returns the profile attributes in an array on the Subscriber object under the Attributes property.